# Problem validating a certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

A site my application submits requests to recently updated their SSL certificate and since that change, our requests have been failing with the well know certificate exception:

`requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXX.YYY', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))`

Normally, I understand this would be an issue of the root cert in the chain not being present in the root store; however, unless I'm misunderstanding something that doesn't appear to be the case here as I'm able to successfully make requests to other sites with the exact same root certificate (as identified by its fingerprints) and I've verified that that certificate exists in the `certifi` `cacerts.pem`.  Are there other causes for this exception?

Comparing the two certificates (working and non working) there are differences in the signature algorithm and public key size in the intermediate CA and server cert portions; could a lack of support for the algorithm lead to this error as well?

I am working with:

- Amazon Linux 2
- Python 3.8
- OpenSSL 1.0.2-fips

Working cert has:

- Server

  - Public Key: RSA 2048
  - Signature Algorithm: SHA-256 with RSA Encryption
- Intermediate

  - Public Key: RSA 2048
  - Signature Algorithm: SHA-384 with RSA Encryption

Failing cert has:

- Server

  - Public Key: RSA 2048
  - Signature Algorithm: SHA-384 with RSA Encryption
- Intermediate

  - Public Key: RSA 3072
  - Signature Algorithm: SHA-384 with RSA Encryption

Comment: I'd say that it is more logical that the intermediate certificate is not present in the chain provided by the server. It needs to at least send the leaf certificate and the intermediate, in that order.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MaartenBodewes.  However, the cert is verified just fine in browsers and in other clients, like curl--that seems to me to indicate its something in the tool chain Python is using rather than the actual cert configuration.  When I force curl to use the root certificate store Python is using with the --cacert option, it still verifies the certificate successfully.

Comment: They still may have been cached. What do you get if you do `openssl s_client` with the `-showcerts` option?

Comment: @MichaelC.O'Connor: There can also be problems that the various tools you try and up add different endpoints and thus get different certificates. One common issue is a different configuration for IPv4 and IPv6, another that the URL tested is not exactly the same (i.e. www.example.com vs. example.com), another that different DNS servers are used and only some have the right mapping etc. I recommend that you include the verbose output of `curl -v` and `openssl s_client` in your question. Helpful would also be if you provide the actual URL.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestions.  I spoke with the maintainer of the service and he said they needed to update the chain on the load balancer to address  the change in the intermediate, so perhaps you initial suggestion was correct, @MaartenBodewes.

Comment: Probably. Error is likely correct. Leaf cert is present, root cert is present. Elementary, my dear Watson ;)